# ios textfield inside tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have created 2 textfields inside 2 cells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self CustomTextField:cell :txtFirstName];
        txtFirstName.text = [_dictInfoOneUser objectForKey:@"firstname"];
        [cell addSubview:txtFirstName];
        txtFirstName.tag = 100;
    }
    else (indexPath.row == 1){
        [self CustomTextField:cell :txtLastName];
        txtLastName.text = [_dictInfoOneUser objectForKey:@"lastname"];
        [cell addSubview:txtLastName];
        txtLastName.tag = 101;
    }
}
```

I think I set `txtFirstName.text = [_dictInfoOneUser objectForKey:@"firstname"];`. I edited cell firstname, after that, I scroll, it's refresh cell and reset my edited in textfield.

how to I can resolve this problem.

************ Edited

```
-(void)CustomTextField :(UITableViewCell *)cell :(UITextField *)textField{
    //add bottom border
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width / 2 - 160, textField.frame.size.height - 1, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = 1;
    [textField.layer addSublayer:border];
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [textField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

Comment: Have you saved edited info? If no - than you just have 'default' text in cells.

Comment: maybe save the edited texts in a NSMutableArray (remove and add each time you make an edit) and use this mutable array to populate the cells. the tableview is reloaded when you scroll.

Comment: Can you edit my code.

Comment: add the code for your `CustomTextField`

Comment: The way you allocate your textFields is weird. They should be created with the cell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not dequeing your cell in the first place, here's what your

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

should look like :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
...
}
```

Comment: `deque`-ing is the modern way to initialize cell, but not the cause of the OP's problem.  The OP is getting a cell.  Without one, the question would be about an exception, not about cell content being displayed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to cell reuse.  The pattern to follow is to *conditionally build* the subviews (so you get only one per cell), but *unconditionally configure* them.  Like this...

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    UITextField *txtFirstName = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    if (!txtFirstName) {
        // it doesn't exist. build it
        [self CustomTextField:cell :txtFirstName];  // not sure what this does, assuming it's part of building it
        [cell addSubview:txtFirstName];
        txtFirstName.tag = 100;
    }
    // whether it was just built or not, give it a value
    txtFirstName.text = [_dictInfoOneUser objectForKey:@"firstname"];
}
// same idea for the other row/textfield
```

Comment: sorry to hear.  this approach is correct, though.  i think the problem is related to the CustomTextField field method.  please add that code to your question